# Steps to create a behavior (how create a behavior)

Tags: xamarin.forms

i need to create a behavior from a view, i am using a class, also namespace to call to behavior but it's not working for me, i do not know what is my wrong, because i am doing all of step to create a behavior.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Layouts.Commands.BasketView"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Layouts;assembly=Layouts"
             Title="Cart">

        <StackLayout Padding="10,60,10,0">
            <Label Text="Red when the number isn't valid" FontSize="Small" />
            <Entry Placeholder="Enter a System.Double" 
            local:NumericValidationBehavior.AttachBehavior="true" />
        </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

in this line i get the error  `local:NumericValidationBehavior.AttachBehavior="true" />`

i have my behavior, but it cannot be instanciate in the view (see code up), there are other step to be instanciate?

```
namespace AttachedNumericValidationBehavior
{
    public static class NumericValidationBehavior
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty AttachBehaviorProperty
            = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("AttachBehavior", typeof(bool), typeof(NumericValidationBehavior), false, propertyChanged: OnAttachBehaviorChanged);

        public static bool GetAttachBehavior(BindableObject view)
        {
            return (bool)view.GetValue(AttachBehaviorProperty);
        }

        public static void SetAttachBehavior(BindableObject view, bool value)
        {
            view.SetValue(AttachBehaviorProperty, value);
        }

        static void OnAttachBehaviorChanged(BindableObject view, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var entry = view as Entry;
            if (entry == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            bool attachBehavior = (bool)newValue;
            if (attachBehavior)
            {
                entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
            }
            else
            {
                entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
            }
        }

        static void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            double result;
            bool isValid = double.TryParse(args.NewTextValue, out result);
            ((Entry)sender).TextColor = isValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

the error is: "AttachBehavior is not in type NumericValidationBehavior"

Comment: what is the specific error message you are getting?

Comment: @Jason is this AttachBehavior is not in type NumericValidationBehavior

Comment: @Jason help me please!!!

Comment: The namespace in your xmlns:local does not match the namespace you are using in your code

Comment: @Jason can you explain me please, how i must put the namespace with a example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You class `NumericValidationBehavior` belongs to namespace `AttachedNumericValidationBehavior`, so when you want to use `NumericValidationBehavior` in xaml, the namespace `local` should be:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AttachedNumericValidationBehavior;"
```

And use the namespace:

```
<StackLayout Padding="10,60,10,0">
    <Label Text="Red when the number isn't valid" FontSize="Small" />
    <Entry Placeholder="Enter a System.Double" 
         local:NumericValidationBehavior.AttachBehavior="true" />
</StackLayout>
```

For more details, see document: [Declaring Namespaces for Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces#declaring-namespaces-for-types)